# Как реализовать движения прогресса в NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: cocoa, macos, objective-c, xcode

Как правильно реализовать движение прогресса в NSProgressIndicator (determinate)?

Сейчас я реализовал его так:

```
    IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *content = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtURL:url includingPropertiesForKeys:nil options:NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles error:nil];

        double countList = (double)[content count];
        [progressIndicator setIndeterminate:NO];
        [progressIndicator setMinValue:0.0];
        [progressIndicator setMaxValue:countList];
        [progressIndicator setDoubleValue:0.0];

        for (NSURL *u in content) {
           Element *e = [[Element alloc] initElement:[u path]];
           [list addObject:e];
           [progressIndicator incrementBy:1.0];
        }
```

Я понимаю, что выставлять `setMaxValue:` количеством файлов это неправильно. Т.е. `progressIndicator` должен быть в фиксированном диапазоне, например, от 0 до 100, а его движение или `incrementBy:count`, в смысле `count`,  должен рассчитываться по формуле.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, формулу, как правильно рассчитывать движение прогресса?

Или если есть другие варианты реализации движения NSProgressIndicator, опишите их, желательно приведите пример или дайте ссылку на полезную статью.

Зарание всех благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите иметь фиксированные границы `NSProgressIndicator`, то можете каждую итерацию вашего цикла прибавлять значение, вычисляемое таким образом `100.0/[content count]`

```
for (NSURL *item in content) {
  Element *temporaryElement = [[Element alloc] initElement:[item path]];
  [list addObject:temporaryElement];
  progressIndicator.progress += 100.0/[content count];
}
```